# How do you organize your directory structure in koa app?

Tags: webpack, sass, koa2

it is too stupid to write css and js in public directory but write templates in views dirctory and when our project is too big, it is too difficult to manage it,and our js and css need to compress and put them in CDN, how can I solve it?

I hava searched it in github, and found some repos about mutil-pages but it is not what I wanted.

I want to write code in this:

```
--views
  --index
     index.pug
     index.sass
     index.js
```

when koa render pug template, the output html hava a link or script tag to them

Hope you can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
--src
  --client
    --assets
      *.cs/js
    --views
      *.html
  --server
    app.js
```